# Behavior and mixed strategies: extensive form game with perfect recall

Tags: game-theory

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tT0E7PaDVck) video there is a game with perfect recall, see the snippet below. They claim that they have an example of a mixed strategy that is not a behavior strategy. However the following holds and is stated in the book by [Maschler: Game Theory](http://62.182.86.140/main/1161000/47cbd612cc702a8c4677a38623e532d3/Michael%20Maschler%2C%20Eilon%20Solan%2C%20Shmuel%20Zamir%20-%20Game%20Theory-Cambridge%20University%20Press%20%282013%29.pdf):

```
Theorem 6.15 (Kuhn [1957]) In every game in extensive form, if player i has perfect
recall, then for every mixed strategy of player i there exists an equivalent behavior strategy.
```

**This seems a contradiction to me.**

**EDIT** What is the equivalent behavior strategy for this mixed one:
$$(.6(A,G),.4(B,H))$$

The answer will shed some light on my OQ.

**EDIT2** I've tried to solve this:
$$p\cdot s=0.6$$ and
$$(1-p)\cdot (1-s)=0.4$$

but this system has only imaginary solutions.

Here, $p$ is probability taking action $A$ and $s$ taking $G$.
[image]

Comment: Could you explain the notation $(.6(A,G),.4(B,H))$? It doesn't appear to be a valid strategy at all.

Comment: @aschepler It is a convex mixture between the choices at the root where 1st player chooses $A$ and at the node on the right bottom where the first player chooses $G$. Hence $(A,G)$ says what to do at all nodes where 1st player is to move. Similarly for $.4(B,H)$ Also/hence, and most importantly **$(A,G)$ is a particular pure strategy**. Similarly for $(B,H)$. The convex mixture of these two pure strategies is then a mixed strategy. See the entire video. Is it clear now ? And now, I'm looking for the **equivalent behavior** strategy for this mixed one.

Comment: @aschepler Behavior strategy for the 1st player is supposed to claim what to do at each vertex  at which  1st is to move. Hence $(A,G)$ is not a proper strategy for behavior strategy type.

Comment: So perhaps the "contradiction" is from differing conventions where the video considers the example as technically a mixed strategy, even though one of its entries is an "improper" strategy; but Maschler's theorem applies only to mixed strategies based on "proper" pure strategies?

Comment: @aschepler I know some of the work by Michael Maschler, because my thesis was about his bargaining set, namely the computation of it. But any answer to my Q. how to convert that mixed strategy given  would imply immediately in awarding you to the bounty started. Could you compute what to do by 1st player at choices $A/B$ and $G/H$ given that mixed strategy with 0.4 and 0.6 ? Do we need at all to know what to do at $E/F$ ? Perhaps applying this node strategy of 2nd player would eliminate the imaginarity of $p$ as given at the bounty description ? BWT what do you mean by *proper* and *improper*

Comment: I thought I meant the same as you in "$(A,G)$ is not a proper strategy for behavior strategy type", but maybe not. The strange thing to me is that if the pure strategy selects $A$, then the choice between $G$ and $H$ can never come up. Or do the definitions/notation require/allow a pure strategy to describe every node for the player, even if some are irrelevant?

Comment: @aschepler Yes, exactly. And with the *proper* and *improper* strategy you are also right. But it turns out that the choices arising from mixed strategies they give **imaginary** probabilities for behavior strategy.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the confusion here arises because of the meaning of "equivalent strategies". Two strategies of Player 1 (they can be mixed strategies, behavior strategies, or one mixed and the other behavior) are equivalent if for every strategy of the other player (be it mixed or behavior), the two pairs induce the same probability distribution over the leaves of the tree.
For example, when Player 1 selects A in her first decision node, the play cannot reach her second decision node, and hence the pure strategies (A,G) and (A,H) of Player 1 are equivalent under this definition.

Now, Kuhn's Theorem states that in games with perfect recall every mixed strategy has an equivalent behavior strategy, and vice versa. Since the game discussed here has perfect recall, Kuhn's Theorem holds in this case.
The mixed strategy ( 0.6(A,G), 0.4(B,H) ) selects with probability 0.6 the pure strategy (A,G), and with probability 0.4 the pure strategy (B,H). The behavior strategy that is equivalent to it is: in the first decision node, select the mixed action (0.6 A, 0.4 B), and in the second decision node, select H with probability 1.

Note that mixed strategies and behavior strategies are mathematically different objects. A mixed strategy is a probability distribution over pure strategies (where a pure strategy is a function from the set of all information sets of the player to actions), while a behavior strategy is a function from the set of all information sets of the player to mixed actions. So a mixed strategy cannot be a behavior strategy - they lie in different spaces. Yet, as Kuhn's Theorem states, there is a natural equivalence between these two classes of strategies.